# How to reset the state of bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dialog, modal-dialog

I have twitter bootstrap Modal Dialog with scrollbar.My issue is that when I have opened it the first time and dragged scrollbar down and closed it,the second time when I open the dialog the scrollbar is at the bottom of the dialog.I want the scrollbar to be reset when the user opens it again.

How do I reset the state of the modal dialog to its original state

see my [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Pw4hkLUhdn)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One easy solution to this is to remove the fade class from the modal, and in your click event add:

```
$('.modal-content').scrollTop(0);
```

But fading looks nice, so...

Bootstrap gives us an event to call functions after the modal is shown:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e){
    $('.modal-content').scrollTop(0);
});
```

The problem with this is that you can see the modal quickly jump position as it opens. The alternative is to use the 'hide.bs.modal' event which resets the scroll bar as you are closing the modal. If this is a problem for you then you'll need to modify some bootstrap css classes I think.

Comment: Thanks,I tried 'hide.bs.modal' event and it works great